# AJAX Jquery refreshing ALL content but I want NEW content only

Tags: ajax, jquery, partial-page-refresh

I may be reinventing the wheel but that's intentional. I am trying to make a real-time chat application using PHP HTML MySQL CSS. It's working quite well over the network and grabbing new content every second. In IE you can notice a flicker every second, seemingly it is pulling all that data again and again, even if there's no new content, and I don't like that.

Here is my refresh JS code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#data").load("data.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#data").load('data.php');
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

data.php is just a while looping through all the database records and showing them:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<p><b>". $poster ."</b>: ". $message ."<br /><span style='font-size: 10px;'>". date('D d M - g:i:s a', strtotime($row['when'])) ."</span></p>";
    }
```

I've looked and looked on the internet for solutions, fading etc, I can't think of how to accomplish this, surely there is some nice and easy and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a time stamp to the server of the last update and only retrieve new content.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, that I personally use in my shoutboxes, is to set a variable in the loaded data with a global variable.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var global_var = 1234;
</script>
<p>HTML CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
```

Then when you call data.php you can call it with this new parameter.

```
$("#data").load('data.php?var=' + global_var );
```

Your global_var can be anything, from last inserted ID, or last timestamp, or???

Comment: I like the idea of the last ID, so I did this, I am novice with JS:

$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM irb_posts";
Got the max value... then...

var global_var = <?php echo $row['MAX(id)'] ?>;

The inital time the page is loaded it will get ALL data.
Subsequent times it will get data with ID > the max ID.

However this is replacing all my existing data. Do I need to change it to append somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This one is what you need, you only have to modify it for your needs:

[Refresh a div's content only if new content is added to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424795/refresh-a-divs-content-only-if-new-content-is-added-to-the-database/)

This will pass the time when the page was loaded, and will refresh the data only if new content has been added, see the first answer.

All the best ;).